# Tor on Firefox OS

Tags: mobile

How can I use Tor on Firefox OS? Is there anything like Orbot or a browser bundle for Firefox OS based phones?

Answer (score 2):

No, currently there is no way to use Tor on Firefox OS based phones, because there is no way to run the Tor program on Firefox OS. But it might be possible in the future, though no projects are working on it right now

> We've *[Guardian Project]* talked to Mozilla multiple times about this possibility. They
>   even invited us to a special event in Mountain View around a "secure
>   Firefox phone".
>
> The main issue is that they don't want to allow native binaries to run
>   on the device as part of apps themselves. We can easily write an
>   HTML/JS controller GUI, aka OrbotHTML, but we can't bundle in a native
>   Tor arm binary into that app, apparently.

- source: Nathan Frietas, Orbot developer [Jul 2013, Tor-talk mailing list](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2013-July/028740.html)

**However**, there is now a [Javascript implementation of Tor](https://github.com/Ayms/node-Tor) that could potentially be ported to Firefox OS, but there are currently no plans in progress to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If I may: The real problem seems to be that JavaScript is essential to Firefox OS and JavaScript is a big no no for Tor. From https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2013-July/028740.html we see

> They said we must cross-compile any native code into Javascript. I am
>   not sure if that was meant to be a joke or not.

and at http://archives.seul.org/or/talk/Jul-2013/msg00121.html you can see this explicitly stated as:

> That is the rub, obviously. A FirefoxOS phone is built around the concept of JavaScript as the primary application programming language. If JavaScript is off, then the phone might as well be bricked.